# How to create instance of object using reflection for class that have parameter in constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to create object using reflection with class that have parameter in constructor.

This is what I try for class without constructor.

```
ABC::class.createInstance()
```

But I have no idea how to do this for class with constructor like

```
class ABC(a: Int, b: Int) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABC::class.getConstructor(Int::class, Int::class).newInstance(firstInt, secondInt)
```

Comment: Thank so much. It's works. Anyway, are there any possible solution for `kotlin.reflect` to do something like this?